# fsockopen equivalent perl

Tags: php, perl

I've just run into a problem with my ISP who it seems refuses to allow me to use `fsockopen` telling me its a security risk and that I have to find an alternative suggesting that I use perl.

Does anyone have an alternative to fsockopen possibly using perl for the script below?

```
<?php

// fetches server information from minequery.
function fetch_server_info($ip, $port){
    $socket = fsockopen($ip, $port, $errno, $errstr, 0.5);

    if($socket === false){
        return false;   
    }

    fwrite($socket, "QUERY_JSON\n");

    $responce = stream_get_contents($socket);

    return json_decode($responce, true);
}

?>
```

Comment: IO::Socket, but I don't see how switching from one way to open a socket to another will help the "security risk".

Comment: They have no idea of what they're talking about... or just giving you a B.S reason for the existing server configuration.

Comment: Thinking about this more, I'd guess their admin configured PHP to block socket access on their hosting infrastructure -- probably because they've not properly isolated their customer-hosting DMZ. Using another language (Perl) not subject to configurable limitations on sockets is mostly likely the backhanded advice of a staffer used to getting around these conditions.

Comment: You might be able to use a combination of `fopen` and `fpassthru` to accomplish the same thing.

Comment: The usual way to disable sockets in PHP is to simply comment out extension=sockets.so, which would mean that any way you do it (short of using dlopen) would fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want to get the response from the server into `$responce` without using any of the socket functions in PHP. If shell_exec() is enabled by your hosting provider, you can run an external program to do this instead. Here's an example using perl:

```
<?php

// fetches server information from minequery.
function fetch_server_info($ip, $port){
    $script = <<<'EOF'
use warnings;
use strict;
use IO::Socket;

die if $#ARGV+1 != 2;
my $ip = $ARGV[0];
my $port = $ARGV[1];
my $sock = IO::Socket::INET->new(PeerAddr => "$ip:$port") or die;
print $sock "QUERY_JSON\n" or die;
local $/ = undef;
print <$sock>;
EOF;

    $responce = shell_exec("echo '$script' | perl - $ip $port");

    if ($responce == NULL)
        return false;

    return json_decode($responce, true);
}

$>
```

Or you could use netcat if they have it:

```
<?php

// fetches server information from minequery.
function fetch_server_info($ip, $port){
    $responce = shell_exec("echo QUERY_JSON| nc $ip $port");

    if ($responce == NULL)
        return false;

    return json_decode($responce, true);
}

$>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, i have tried it out and it worked perfectly